# Passing function inside functionPassing function inside function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

PHP:

```
echo '<div id="div1" onClick="return alerting(\'Hellow\', \'divtext(\'div1\');\', \'Passing...\');"> Click </div>'; `
```

Javascript:

```
function divtext(div){    
  document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = 'Sucess!';
}

function alerting(alert1, functionpass, alert2){  
  alert(alert1);   
  eval(functionpass);
  alert(alert2);   
}
```

What happens is that the javascript function to handle the error there without it being \ in quotes.

Any method which puts \ in quotes inside the function after it is called?

Answer (score 1):

Running the above PHP function [results in the HTML](http://codepad.org/aqFmZWnw):

```
<div id="div1" onClick="return alerting('Hellow', 'divtext('div1');', 'Passing...');"> Click </div>
```

You can tell this will not work, `'divtext('div1');'`.

Try changing the PHP code to:

```
echo '<div id="div1" onClick="return alerting(\'Hellow\', \'divtext(&quot;div1&quot;);\', \'Passing...\');"> Click </div>';
```

[This produces a value of](http://codepad.org/x7lGAHZS):

```
<div id="div1" onClick="return alerting('Hellow', 'divtext(&quot;div1&quot;);', 'Passing...');"> Click </div>
```

[Which then works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/bHYwx/).